# hibernate multiple threads prevent multiple save(), JTA necessary?

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions, synchronization, jta

I'm using a hibernate session per request model for my web application.  My jdbc transaction begins at the beginning of each web request and commited at the end.

// Non-managed environment idiom

```
Session sess = factory.openSession();
Transaction tx = null;
try {
    tx = sess.beginTransaction();

    // do some work
    ...

    tx.commit();
}
catch (RuntimeException e) {
    if (tx != null) tx.rollback();
    throw e; // or display error message
}
finally {
    sess.close();
}
```

I'm faced with the problem where I am testing for existence of an entity (A) based on several parameters and doing an insert only if it doesn't exist.

```
public synchronized myMethod(param1, param2) {
    MyEntityA entity = MyEntityADAO.findEntity(param1, param2)
    if (entity == null) {
        entity = .../create entity
        MyEntityADAO.save(entity);
    }
}
```

the problem is that synchronization does not help because the call to MyEntityADAO.save() does not actually write to the database when the currently running thread exits the method and releases the lock, the write to the database occurs after the transaction is commited which is generally what I need for my application except for a few scenarios.  The code above causes multiple records saved with same parameters in a multithreaded environment.

I've tried to execute the save code in its own new session and transaction:

```
public synchronized myMethod(param1, param2) {
    MyEntityA entity = MyEntityADAO.findEntity(param1, param2)
    if (entity == null) {
        entity = .../create entity
        Session session = HibernateUtil.createSession();
        MyEntityADAO.save(entity);
        Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();

   }
}
```

the above causes problems with 2 open sessions loading the same collection with hibernate in some instances.

Should I enclose every DAO call in its own transaction and use transaction propagation with JTA? Is there a way to avoid JTA? Is it alright to commit transaction associated with the main session after the call to MyEntityADAO.save() and call beginTransaction on the main session right after and have the transaction commited at the end of the request as it does now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me and my particular app requirements trying to avoid JTA and nested transactions:

Using ManagedSessionContext because org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext will close and create a new session for each transaction.  You will run into problems with entities that have collections associated if you load those entities in multiple open sessions (when you will create multiple transactions for one request).

- I open a hibernate session and bind it to the context in the beginning of my web request
- Any service layer method that needs test for existence prior to insert is marked synchronized, the global transaction is commited with the insert statement and a new transaction is started
- At the end the request the transaction bound to the session is commited

  public synchronized myMethod(param1, param2) {

  ```
   MyEntityA entity = MyEntityADAO.findEntity(param1, param2)
   if (entity == null) {
        entity = .../create entity

        MyEntityADAO.save(entity);
        HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit();
        HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().begin();


   }
  ```

  }

I know its ugly and will not work for everybody in every scenerio, but after doing a very intense search on transaction management, isolation levels, locking, versioning that is the only solution I have found that worked for me.  I am not using Spring, and I'm not using a Java EE container, using Tomcat 6.

Answer (score 0):

The coherence of the data in database should not be compromised by doing only some part of an atomic change in its own transaction. And although some synchronization might work on your environment, if you need to cluster your app, or if several applications acces the database, it won't solve the problem.

What you should do is to put a unique constraint in the database on `[param1 - param2]`. That will cause one of the two transactions to rollback if there is a race condition.

If you choose to still isolate the check/insert code in its own transaction (because it's not a problem if that succeeds and the outer transaction fails), I don't see how JTA would be a problem. Supposing you're using EJBs or Spring, just put this method in its own EJB/bean, and mark the method as transactional, with the REQUIRES_NEW propagation.

The code would thus look like this:

```
// some code
Long id = myBean.checkIfExistOrCreate(param1, param2); // this methos call starts a new transaction
// now we're sure that the entity exists. Load it in the current session.
MyEntity e = em.find(MyEntity.class, id);
```

If you can't synchronize `checkIfExistOrCreate`, then try calling it, catch any exception that it could throw, and retry calling it:

```
Long id = null;
try {
    id = myBean.checkIfExistOrCreate(param1, param2);
}
catch (Exception e) { // a well-defined exception would be better
    // the transaction roled back: retry
    id = myBean.checkIfExistOrCreate(param1, param2);
}
// now we're sure that the entity exists. Load it in the current session.
MyEntity e = em.find(MyEntity.class, id);
```

Comment: thank you for your input.  I do have the constraints set up but I'm not catching any hibernate/jdbc exceptions in my dao/service layer. seems like a great idea.  thank you.

Comment: i'm catching the ConstraintViolationException and attempting to get the existing entity in the catch block and getting a null..is there some intermediate stage when the transaction is marked as if "completed" in the underlying db (mysql) and the table constraints are "updated" but the database won't return the new row yet from the table?

Comment: i've tried flushing the session instead inside the synchronized method/block after the save()..get the exception less often but still didn't solve the problem

Comment: flushing won't help. Transactions normally run in isolation of each other, and with the traditional default isolation level (READ_COMMITTED), the transaction B won't see anything inserted in the database by transaction A until A has committed.

Comment: with READ_COMMITED isolation level for your solution to work you still need to commit the transaction that is doing the INSERT before exiting the synchronized block, the test for existence inside your catch block will result in a null.